Arduino Serial Data Not Publishing Correctly to Flask Frontend
I'm working on a project where I'm reading serial data from an Arduino using Python and displaying it on a web frontend built with Flask. The Arduino connection seems to be working fine, and I'm able to read the data correctly in the backend. However, when I try to send this data to the frontend via an API endpoint, the status always shows as disconnected and the data points are None.
The Problem:
The logs show that the Arduino is connected and returning status data correctly (e.g., {'x_pos': 0, 'y_pos': 0, 'sg_x': 0, 'sg_y': 0}).
However, when I access the /api/status endpoint, the response shows "connected": False and all other values are None.
Example log output:
INFO:__main__:Ping sent. Connected: True, Status: {'x_pos': 100, 'y_pos': 300, 'sg_x': 0, 'sg_y': 37}
INFO:__main__:Sending status to client: {'connected': False, 'x_pos': None, 'y_pos': None, 'sg_x': None, 'sg_y': None}
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [02/Sep/2024 14:13:17] "GET /api/status HTTP/1.1" 200 -

What would be the reason for the check_status not to have access to the status?
Here's my full code:
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify, send_from_directory
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
import threading
from threading import Lock
import time
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)
status_lock = Lock()

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

arduino_arm = None
arduino_arm_connected = False
last_response = ""
arduino_status = None

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/static/<path:path>')
def send_static(path):
    return send_from_directory('static', path)

def init_serial_connections():
    global arduino_arm
    try:
        ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
        logger.info("Available Ports:")
        for p in ports:
            logger.info(str(p))

        arduino_arm = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200, timeout=1)
        logger.info("Serial connections established")
        time.sleep(2)  # Wait for Arduino to reset
    except serial.SerialException as e:
        logger.error(f"Error initializing serial connections: {e}")
        logger.info("Trying to close and reopen the ports...")
        try:
            if arduino_arm:
                arduino_arm.close()
            arduino_arm = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200, timeout=1)
            logger.info("Serial connections re-established")
        except serial.SerialException as e:
            logger.error(f"Failed to re-establish serial connections: {e}")

def check_connection(arduino):
    if arduino is None or not arduino.is_open:
        return False, None
    try:
        arduino.write(b"PING\n")
        arduino.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)  # Give Arduino time to respond
        response = arduino.readline().decode().strip()
        if response.startswith("STATUS:"):
            # Parse the status information
            status_info = response.split(':')[1].split(',')
            status_dict = {
                'x_pos': int(status_info[0][1:]),
                'y_pos': int(status_info[1][1:]),
                'sg_x': int(status_info[2][3:]),
                'sg_y': int(status_info[3][3:])
            }
            return True, status_dict
        elif response:
            # If we get any non-empty response, consider it as connected
            return True, None
        else:
            # If we get an empty response, consider it as not connected
            return False, None
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error checking connection: {e}")
        return False, None

def read_arduino_data():
    global arduino_arm, arduino_arm_connected, last_response, arduino_status
    last_message_time = time.time()
    ping_interval = 0.1  
    connection_timeout = 2.0 
    reconnect_interval = 5.0  

    while True:
        current_time = time.time()
        
        if not arduino_arm or not arduino_arm.is_open:
            try:
                logger.info("Attempting to (re)connect to Arduino...")
                arduino_arm = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200, timeout=1)
                time.sleep(2)  # Wait for Arduino to reset
                logger.info("Arduino (re)connected successfully")
                with status_lock:
                    arduino_arm_connected = True
            except serial.SerialException as e:
                logger.error(f"Failed to (re)connect to Arduino: {e}")
                with status_lock:
                    arduino_arm_connected = False
                    arduino_status = None
                time.sleep(reconnect_interval)
                continue

        try:
            if arduino_arm.in_waiting:
                data = arduino_arm.readline().decode().strip()
                if data:
                    logger.info(f"Arduino: {data}")
                    last_response = data
                    last_message_time = current_time
                    if data.startswith("STATUS:"):
                        with status_lock:
                            arduino_arm_connected = True
                            status_info = data.split(':')[1].split(',')
                            arduino_status = {
                                'x_pos': int(status_info[0][1:]),
                                'y_pos': int(status_info[1][1:]),
                                'sg_x': int(status_info[2][3:]),
                                'sg_y': int(status_info[3][3:])
                            }
            elif current_time - last_message_time > ping_interval:
                # If no message received in the ping interval, send a ping
                connected, ping_status = check_connection(arduino_arm)
                with status_lock:
                    arduino_arm_connected = connected
                    if connected and ping_status:
                        arduino_status = ping_status
                    elif current_time - last_message_time > connection_timeout:
                        arduino_status = None
                last_message_time = current_time
                logger.info(f"Ping sent. Connected: {arduino_arm_connected}, Status: {arduino_status}")
        except serial.SerialException as e:
            logger.error(f"Error reading from Arduino: {e}")
            arduino_arm.close()
            with status_lock:
                arduino_arm_connected = False
                arduino_status = None

        time.sleep(0.01)

@app.route('/api/status', methods=['GET'])
def check_status():
    global arduino_arm_connected, arduino_status
    with status_lock:
        status = {
            "connected": arduino_arm_connected,
            "x_pos": arduino_status['x_pos'] if arduino_status else None,
            "y_pos": arduino_status['y_pos'] if arduino_status else None,
            "sg_x": arduino_status['sg_x'] if arduino_status else None,
            "sg_y": arduino_status['sg_y'] if arduino_status else None
        }
    logger.info(f"Sending status to client: {status}")
    return jsonify(status)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_serial_connections()
    
    # Start the Arduino reading thread
    threading.Thread(target=read_arduino_data, daemon=True).start()
    
    # Run the Flask app
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)

Ensuring proper use of threading locks with status_lock.
Logging the status right before sending it to the client to see if the values are being set correctly.
Checking for any possible race conditions that might cause the status to be reset before the API responds.
